# Merge if properties are equal and remove

Tags: java

Below is my code (can be copy paste in https://www.compilejava.net/ with `-ea` as command line option).

I have an `Object` called `Main`. I have `Main` inside a `List`. If 2 properties (`a` and `b`) are equal to another `Main` object in the `list`, property `strings` should be concatenated. Furthermore, duplicates (when the 2 properties are equal) should than be removed (so the `list` can not contain 2 or more `Mains` in which both `a` and `b` are the same).

I tried it with a `HashMap`, `hashCode`, but I can not figure it out well. Note: I use OpenJDK-12 and can not use newer versions.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Main {

    final int a;
    final int b;
    final List<String> strings;

    Main(int a, int b, List<String> strings) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.strings = strings;
    }

    private static Main generateMain0() {
        return new Main(0, 1, createListWithOneElement("merge me with main1"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main0 = generateMain0();
        Main main1 = new Main(0, 1, createListWithOneElement("merge me with main2"));
        Main main2 = new Main(0, 2, createListWithOneElement("leave me alone"));
        Main main3 = new Main(0, 2, createListWithOneElement("leave me alone also"));

        List<Main> mains = new ArrayList<>();

        mains.add(main0);
        mains.add(main1);
        mains.add(main2);
        mains.add(main3);

        // Do magic here to remove duplicate and concat property strings

        // main1 should be removed, since property a and b were equal to main0 property a and b
        assert mains.size() == 3;

        Main main0Copy = generateMain0();

        main0Copy.strings.add("merge me with main2");

        // The first element should be main0. It should also contain
        // the strings of main1 since property a and b were equal
        assert mains.get(0).equals(main0Copy);
        assert mains.get(1).equals(main2);
        assert mains.get(2).equals(main3);
    }

    private static List<String> createListWithOneElement(String value) {
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();

        l.add(value);

        return l;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Main main = (Main) o;
        return a == main.a &&
                b == main.b &&
                strings.equals(main.strings);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(a, b, strings);
    }
}
```

Comment: (Just a note to your first `assert`): `List`s are not `Set`s, they don't remove duplicate elements on insert

Comment: @codeflush.dev yes I know, in the 'do magic' comment I expect code to filter out if 2 mains have both a and b equality. Making it a set would also not work, because of the way hashcode/equals is implemented for Main (and I don't want to override equals with only property a and b)

Comment: Are you allowed to use a custom `List`-Implementation ?

Comment: @codeflush.dev yes, and I use Open-JDK-12 and can not use a newer version

Comment: Do you need an implementation of `java.util.List` or can it be a fully custom implementation which does what you need ?

Comment: @codeflush.dev it can be custom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as you said in the comments, you can use a fully custom `List`, you can try the code below.

Internally, it uses a combination of a `List` and a `Map` to find out if a combination of `a` and `b` was already added to the "List". If yes, it adds all `strings` of the given `Main` to the existing `Main`. If not, it adds the given `Main` the the list.

```java
package example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainList {

    private final List<Main> mains;
    private final Map<Key, Main> lookup;

    public MainList() {
        this.mains = new ArrayList<>();
        this.lookup = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Main get(int index) {
        return this.mains.get(index);
    }

    public void add(Main main) {
        final Key key = new Key(main.a, main.b);
        Main existingMain = this.lookup.get(key);

        if (existingMain == null) {
            this.mains.add(main);
            this.lookup.put(key, main);
        } else {
            existingMain.strings.addAll(main.strings);
        }
    }

    public void remove(Main main) {
        final Key key = new Key(main.a, main.b);
        Main existingMain = this.lookup.get(key);

        if (existingMain != null) {
            if (existingMain.equals(main)) {
                this.mains.remove(existingMain);
                this.lookup.remove(key);
            } else {
                existingMain.strings.removeAll(main.strings);
            }
        }
    }

    public void remove(int index) {
        final Main removedMain = this.mains.remove(index);
        final Key key = new Key(removedMain.a, removedMain.b);

        this.lookup.remove(key);
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.mains.size();
    }

    private static class Key {

        private final int a;
        private final int b;

        private Key(int a, int b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object object) {
            if (this == object) {
                return true;
            } else if (object == null || getClass() != object.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            Key key = (Key) object;
            return this.a == key.a && this.b == key.b;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return 31 * this.a + 31 * this.b;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is way better than what I had :)